# Efficient use of conditional statements over dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I want to check in what combination do these values exist and one condition is that hashtag can not exit alone so the combination is 4C1 + 5C2 + 5C3 + 5C4 + 5C5 that makes up these conditional statements.

I want to know whether there is a more efficient way of doing this by using dictionary methods in python.

My Dictionary

```py
data = { 'all_words': '', 'exact_phrase': '', 'any_words': '', 'not_words': '', 'hashtag': ''}
```

My conditional statements

```py
        if data['all_words'] is not None and (data['any_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words']
        elif data['any_words'] is not None and (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['any_words']
        elif data['exact_phrase'] is not None and (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase']
        elif data['hashtag'] is not None and (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'], data['exact_phrase'] is None):
            c.Search = data['hashtag']

        elif (data['all_words'], data['any_words'] is not None) and (data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['any_words']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'] is not None) and (data['any_words'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['not_words'] is not None) and (data['any_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['not_words']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['any_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['any_words'], data['exact_phrase'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['hashtag'], data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words']
        elif (data['any_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['any_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['any_words'], data['not_words'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words']
        elif (data['exact_phrase'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['not_words']
        elif (data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['exact_phrase'] is None):
            c.Search = data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']

        elif (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['exact_phrase'] is not None) and (data['hashtag'], data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'] is not None) and (data['hashtag'], data['exact_phrase'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['not_words'], data['exact_phrase'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'] is not None) and (data['any_words'], data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['not_words']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['any_words'], data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['any_words'], data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['exact_phrase'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'] is not None) and (data['hashtag'], data['all_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words']
        elif (data['exact_phrase'], data['any_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['not_words'], data['all_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['any_words'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'] is None):
            c.Search = data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['all_words'], data['any_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']

        elif (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'] is not None) and (data['hashtag'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['any_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['not_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['exact_phrase'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['any_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
        elif (data['exact_phrase'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag'] is not None) and (data['all_words'] is None):
            c.Search = data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']

        elif (data['all_words'], data['exact_phrase'], data['any_words'], data['not_words'], data['hashtag']) is not None:
            c.Search = data['all_words'] + " " + data['exact_phrase'] + " " + data['any_words'] + " " + data['not_words'] + " " + data['hashtag']
```

Comment: im pretty sure they are almost identical in terms of efficiency ... (maybe the if statements win by a small small margin) ... but it might help make the code more readable

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should learn to use variables to reduce repetition in code.
Also, go see the basic of python dict [python dict](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/dictionary-manipulation-in-python)

I try the rewrite your code tell if that you want the program to execute

```
def not_none_dict(d):
    new_d = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if d[k] is not None or d[k] == '':
            new_d[k] = d[k]
    return new_d

def format_dict(d):
    all_words = new_data.get('all_words', '')
    exact_phrase = new_data.get('exact_phrase', '')
    any_words = new_data.get('any_words', '')
    not_words = new_data.get('not_words', '')
    hashtag = new_data.get('hashtag', '')
    Search = '{}{}{}{}{}'.format(all_words, exact_phrase, any_words, not_words, hashtag)
    print(Search)
    Search = ' '.join(Search)
    return Search

data = {'all_words': '1', 'exact_phrase': '2', 'any_words': None, 'not_words': '4', 'hashtag': None}
new_data = not_none_dict(data)
print(new_data)

if len(new_data) == 0 or new_data is None:
    Search = 'error'
elif len(new_data) == 1:
    Search = list(new_data.values())[0]
elif len(new_data) == len(data):
    Search = format_dict(new_data)
else:
    Search = format_dict(new_data)

print (Search)
```